# Find the overlap between two timestamps in R to assign shifts

Tags: r, datetime, timestamp, overlap, schedule

**Problem**

Currently, I have a large flight crew schedule dataset, with a start and end time, where my goal is to identify whether an employee was working a night shift. A night shift is defined as any portion of the shift between 01:00:00 and 05:59:59. I have looked at functions such as %overlaps%, but these seem not to work for only timestamps. Some sample data (in UTC-tz):

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(start = ymd_hms(c("2018-09-19 23:30:00", "2018-09-19 17:00:00", "2018-09-22 04:30:00")),
                 end = ymd_hms(c('2018-09-20 07:05:00', "2018-09-19 21:00:00", "2018-09-22 12:00:00")))
```

**Solution**

Ideally, I would like to get the following output, with a Boolean variable indicating whether the employee worked a night shift:

```
               start                 end    night.shift
2018-09-19 23:30:00 | 2018-09-20 07:05:00 |  TRUE
2018-09-19 17:00:00 | 2018-09-19 21:00:00 |  FALSE
2018-09-22 04:30:00 | 2018-09-22 12:00:00 |  TRUE
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `seq.POSIXt`

```
transform(df, night.shift=mapply(\(x, y) any(
  as.POSIXct(outer(as.Date(c(x, y)), c('01:00:00', '05:59:59'), paste), tz='GMT') %in% 
    seq.POSIXt(x, y, by='sec')), 
  start, end))
#                 start                 end night.shift
# 1 2018-09-19 23:30:00 2018-09-20 07:05:00        TRUE
# 2 2018-09-19 17:00:00 2018-09-19 21:00:00       FALSE
# 3 2018-09-22 04:30:00 2018-09-22 12:00:00        TRUE
```

or, almost twice as fast, `%inrange%` from the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)

transform(df, night.shift=mapply(\(x, y) any(
  as.POSIXct(outer(as.Date(c(x, y)), c('01:00:00', '05:59:59'), paste), tz='GMT') %inrange% 
    c(x, y)), 
  start, end))
#                 start                 end night.shift
# 1 2018-09-19 23:30:00 2018-09-20 07:05:00        TRUE
# 2 2018-09-19 17:00:00 2018-09-19 21:00:00       FALSE
# 3 2018-09-22 04:30:00 2018-09-22 12:00:00        TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `interval()` or `%--%` to create an `Interval` object and `int_overlaps()` to test if two intervals overlap.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(
    night.shift = int_overlaps(
      (date(start) + hms("01:00:00")) %--% (date(start) + hms("05:59:59")),
      start %--% end
    ) | int_overlaps(
      (date(end) + hms("01:00:00")) %--% (date(end) + hms("05:59:59")),
      start %--% end
    )
  )
```

---

Another way is using `%within%` to check whether a date-time object falls within an interval.

```r
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    night.shift = any(outer(date(c(start, end)), hms(c("01:00:00", "05:59:59")), `+`) %within% (start %--% end))
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

---

###### Output

```r
# # A tibble: 4 × 3
#   start               end                 night.shift
#   <dttm>              <dttm>              <lgl>      
# 1 2018-09-19 23:30:00 2018-09-20 07:05:00 TRUE       
# 2 2018-09-19 17:00:00 2018-09-19 21:00:00 FALSE      
# 3 2018-09-22 04:30:00 2018-09-22 12:00:00 TRUE       
# 4 2018-09-22 04:30:00 2018-09-23 00:30:00 TRUE
```

---

###### Reference

[Utilities for creation and manipulation of Interval objects](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/interval.html)

Comment: Hi Darren, Thanks a lot for your solution! Really appreciate it. However, the proposed solution only looks at the end date, which could provide incorrect outputs for example if you have the following start and end times: start = 2018-09-22 04:30:00, end = 2018-09-23 00:30:00. How do you think we can solve that problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is *super* janky and not optimized, but it works (and was fun to figure out).  You'll want to vectorize it if possible.

```
library(lubridate)
df <- data.frame(start = ymd_hms(c("2018-09-19 23:30:00", "2018-09-19 17:00:00", "2018-09-22 04:30:00")),
                 end = ymd_hms(c('2018-09-20 07:05:00', "2018-09-19 21:00:00", "2018-09-22 12:00:00")))
night <- interval( hms::as_hms(3600), hms::as_hms(21599), tz = "UTC")
print(night)

for(i in 1:3) {
    s = df$start[i]
    f = df$end[i]
    start_seconds = hms::as_hms(60*60*hour(s) + 60*minute(s) + second(s))
    end_seconds = hms::as_hms(60*60*hour(f) + 60*minute(f) + second(f))
    
    interval <- interval(start_seconds, end_seconds, tz = "UTC")
    
    t <- int_overlaps(night, interval)
    print(t)
    
    }
```